Trouble logging to Symfony Monolog Slackwebhookhandler
I'm having trouble logging to Symfony's Slackwebhookhandler via monolog. My entire monolog.yaml is included below. What I dislike the most is that I don't even see any error messages anywhere about how I'm screwing up the config yaml - it just silently fails. What am I doing wrong to get no error messages, and to not be able to log to my slack webhook?
monolog:
channels:
    - deprecation # Deprecations are logged in the dedicated "deprecation" channel when it exists
handlers:
    main:
        type: stream
        path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
        channels: ["!doctrine"]
        formatter: App\Logging\ConciseLineFormatter
    streamout:
        type: stream
        path: php://stdout
        level: debug
        channels: ["!doctrine"]
        formatter: App\Logging\ConciseLineFormatter
    slack:
        type: slackwebhook
        level: debug
        channel: "#notifications-test"
        webhook_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/<MY TOKENS>"


Turns out - cache issue. symfony cache:clear sorted it.
